# Low gpu usage while using TensorFlow

Tags: tensorflow, reinforcement-learning

I wanted to learn about reinforcement learning and I found this article https://blog.paperspace.com/building-a-checkers-gaming-agent-using-neural-networks-and-reinforcement-learning/
Author shows there how to make program which learns how to play checkers with help of RL. When I run this program myself next generations of this algorithm calculates very slowly and I can see that gpu usage is very low. I was running it on two computers. One with windows 10 and rtx3070 8GB of VRAM, task manager was showing around 3-5% usage of card. Second computer was ubuntu 20.04 with rtx3090 24 GB of VRAM, nvidia-smi was showing about 10% usage of card in this case. In both scenarios almost entire VRAM was in usage. In first case it took about 4 hours to calculate 100 generations, in second case it took about 4 hours to calculate 200 generations.
Does the speed of calculations depend on amount of VRAM, is it normal that it shows only about 5% of card usage?

I tried to reinstall tensorflow, CUDA and cudnn a couple times but it didn't help.